# Shibboleth Identity Provider startup exception

Tags: shibboleth

I am trying to get Shibboleth's Identity Provider working on Windows 2008R2. I have Jetty 7 installed and have been able to get to the Jetty Site aka `http://localhost:8080`.
After following instructions on https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/IdPJetty7Prepare and then trying to start Jetty I am getting a IllegalArgumentException.

The output of the shell is below. (its a lot, I've had to cut off some of the stack trace because of StackOverflow's character limit)

I am not a java/jetty/shibboleth guru, so can someone tell me what is going on here?

Thanks

```
PS C:\Jetty> java -jar start.jar
WARNING: System properties and/or JVM args set.  Consider using --dry-run or --exec
2012-12-18 14:48:16.714:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-7.6.8.v20121106
2012-12-18 14:48:16.730:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:Deployment monitor C:\Jetty\webapps at interval 1
2012-12-18 14:48:16.730:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:Deployment monitor C:\Jetty\contexts at interval 1
2012-12-18 14:48:16.730:INFO:oejd.DeploymentManager:Deployable added: C:\Jetty\contexts\test.xml
2012-12-18 14:48:16.808:INFO:oejw.WebInfConfiguration:Extract jar:file:/C:/Jetty/webapps/test.war!/ to C:\Users\Administ
rator\AppData\Local\Temp\jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-test.war-_-any-\webapp
2012-12-18 14:48:17.214:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/,file:/C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/L
ocal/Temp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-test.war-_-any-/webapp/},C:\Jetty/webapps/test.war
2012-12-18 14:48:17.339:INFO:oejs.TransparentProxy:TransparentProxy @ /javadoc-proxy to http://download.eclipse.org/jett
y/stable-7/apidocs
2012-12-18 14:48:17.339:INFO:oejd.DeploymentManager:Deployable added: C:\Jetty\contexts\idp.xml
2012-12-18 14:48:18.246:WARN:oejw.WebAppClassLoader:EXCEPTION
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: !file: jar:file:/C:/Shibboleth/2.3.8/war/idp.war!/WEB-INF/lib/activation-1.1.jar
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.addClassPath(WebAppClassLoader.java:245)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.addJars(WebAppClassLoader.java:282)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration.configure(WebInfConfiguration.java:165)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.configure(WebAppContext.java:454)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1233)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:683)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:480)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:39)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:186)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:494)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:145)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:56)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:609)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:540)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:403)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:337)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:121)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:555)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AggregateLifeCycle.doStart(AggregateLifeCycle.java:81)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:96)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:275)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1266)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1189)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:472)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:95)
2012-12-18 14:48:18.246:WARN:oejw.WebAppClassLoader:EXCEPTION
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: !file: jar:file:/C:/Shibboleth/2.3.8/war/idp.war!/WEB-INF/lib/antlr-2.7.7.jar
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.addClassPath(WebAppClassLoader.java:245)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.addJars(WebAppClassLoader.java:282)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration.configure(WebInfConfiguration.java:165)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.configure(WebAppContext.java:454)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1233)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:683)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:480)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:39)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:186)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:494)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:145)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:56)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:609)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:540)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:403)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:337)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:121)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:555)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AggregateLifeCycle.doStart(AggregateLifeCycle.java:81)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:58)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:96)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:275)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:64)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1266)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1189)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:472)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:620)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:95)
2012-12-18 14:48:18.261:WARN:oejw.WebAppClassLoader:EXCEPTION
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: !file: jar:file:/C:/Shibboleth/2.3.8/war/idp.war!/WEB-INF/lib/antlr-runtime-3.1.3.ja
r
[******** Cut Off to get under StackOverFlow's Character Limit **************************]
```

Comment: Did you ever find out the solution to this problem? I am having the exact same issue and I suspect it is because the URL is of the form:

jar:file:/path/to/file instead of file:/path/to/file but I am not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Unfortunately no, and have hence given up on trying to get Shibboleth up and running.

Answer (score 0):

I started the Shibboleth IDP with Jetty using maven. For your reference I give you here the code of the POM and the installation instructions. Worked fine for me:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.apache</groupId>
<artifactId>shibboleth-idp</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Shibboleth IDP</name>

<build>
    <finalName>idp</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.26</version>
            <configuration>
                <webApp>${basedir}/war/idp.war</webApp>
                <contextPath>/idp</contextPath>
                <connectors>
                    <connector implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                        <port>7777</port>
                        <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
                    </connector>
        <connector implementation="org.mortbay.jetty.security.SslSocketConnector">
            <port>7443</port>
            <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
            <keystore>${basedir}/credentials/idp.jks</keystore>
            <password>KEYSTORE_PASSWORD_HERE</password>
            <keyPassword>PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD_HERE</keyPassword>
        </connector>
                </connectors>
            </configuration>
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
</project>
```

Installation instructions

1. download the latest version of the IDP from

   http://shibboleth.net/downloads/identity-provider/latest/
2. Unpack the zip file
3. cd into the directory and run the install.sh or install.bat command. This script will create a Shibboleth IDP home dir.
4. Save the POM file as pom.xml in the Shibboleth IDP home dir.
5. Make sure to adapt the params for SSL in the POM file, so that they match your system setup and
6. start the Shibboleth IDP from the Shibboleth IDP home dir by entering the command:

   mvn jetty:run-war

Now you may start configuring. Further instructions for configuration can to be found on the [Shibboleth wiki](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/IdPInstall).